# Android Studio device list stuck on loading

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to add a virtual phone to the device list, however, the device list is stuck on loading.

[image: StuckLoading]

I use the default nexus 5 device on AVD:

[image: AVDConfiguration]

I am on Windows 10 and trying to set up Flutter.

Comment: Try restarting your pc. Sometimes that helps as it restarts adb.
Then if started, see if you can find your emulator with `adb devices`.

Comment: try below commands -
1. adb kill-server
2. adb start-server
3. adb devices

Comment: @Bostrot Restarting PC didn't solve the problem and adb device is showing the emlulator

Comment: @Ankita-user3449434 These command just showed the devices and didn't solve the problem

Comment: Have you found a fix yet?

Comment: For me, closing Android Studio, killing all "adb.exe" processes with Task Manager and reopening Android Studio solved it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you have stored your Flutter SDK in Local Disk C, then move it to another *(Non-Admin Location)* disk and then try using Android studio

**Alternatively**:
Simply run your Android Studio as **Administrator** and it will work fine (Although running flutter with Admin privileges is not recommended nor required either)!
I spent 3 hrs looking for a solution and suddenly realized this option and it worked for me

Answer (score 60):

Quick fix on Android Studio:

1. Search anywhere -> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
   )
2. Look for -> Restart Flutter Daemon

[image]

Comment: This woks for me ( Mackbook + Android Studio 4.0.1 + iOS Simulator )
Thx for the Answer.

Comment: how to open this search box? double shift search only file names

Comment: I cannot see 'Restart Flutter Daemon' on the shift+shift search

Answer (score 39):

Go to *File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart* worked for me.

[image: Image of Android Studio]

Comment: This didn't work!
Sometimes just restart helps. so invalidate cache is not required

Answer (score 38):

In my case, it was a faulty adb execution that was running in the background.

The only thing that worked for me was:

- Close Android Studio
- Kill adb process (on Task Manager on Windows)
- Open Android Studio

Comment: Worked for me. I don't have "flutter" on my device.

Comment: this also works for in the Activity Monitor for Mac

Comment: Worked for me. I had multiple adb processes running.

Comment: The `Kill add process` did it for me.

Answer (score 10):

Just run `adb devices` from command prompt while Android Studio is on.

Android Studio will handle the rest.

Comment: Weirdly this isn't the case in my experience. adb devices shows the device, but Android Studio is still stuck on "Loading Devices".

Answer (score 8):

After hours of searching, this is what I found.

```
flutter doctor -v
```

I found that there were some SDK certificates that weren't agreed.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Allowed me to see which agreements that weren't agreed. After that it worked. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 7):

Try reinstalling Flutter and/or resetting the Flutter SDK path under "File > Settings > Languages and Frameworks > Flutter".

Answer (score 5):

Its 100% worked for me

step 1- turned OFF your Wi-Fi

step 2- open C:\Users\abcdcomputer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

[image]

step 3- open command prompt from in this folder

[image]

step 4- type " adb disconnect " command in Command prompt

[image]

step 5- restart android studio

Answer (score 4):

In the path where Flutter is installed, delete the files "flutter.bat.lock" and "lockfile" and restart.
[image]

Comment: Tanx so much mr y.elinx

Answer (score 2):

Restart the ADB  . navigate to your platform-tools path and type the below command .

./adb kill-server
./adb start-server

or in MAC
open Activity monitor and search for adb in search bar and close button click and force quit now you can able to see the connected devices

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you have Power Shell 5.1 or greater (You can run this command to check `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`
- Update Flutter, Dart and Android studio then restart Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

run "flutter clean" on the terminal works for me

Answer (score 1):

After running

```
flutter doctor -v
```

I found out that my ANDROID_SDK_ROOT was not set. Setting it to the correct directory and restarting Android Studio solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

With New Android Studio and New Flutter, I try to `Refresh`
a few times and it's working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can resolve this by running following commands in command line.

```
$ adb kill-server
cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

yes it will throw an error and it means we are good to go

then you should call following command so the `adb` stuff start to work again

```
adb devices
```

Answer (score 1):

For me solution is

I have moved project from one Machine/Computer to another Machine, so Dart path was wrong.

So I have updated Dart path as per new location in new machine.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anyone using macOS, please don't download/upgrade to 1.17.4 of flutter sdk (using with with android studio/intellij). Keep yourself to 1.17.3 even if you are planning for an upgrade . Seems like intellij plugin has bugs with 1.17.4 and i wasted 2-3hrs debugging things until my eyes fell on this thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3892

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MacOS, then there are issues with flutter version `1.17.4`.
Downloading an older version helped for me.

Comment: Update the response with older version details to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Installed Flutter again and issue was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to latest version by clicking flutter upgrade and then going to File-> Invalidate Caches /Restart then press Invalidate and Restart  worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if nothing worked then try this : Download a new and stable version of Flutter SDK [from here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk) , point path of your flutter sdk from settings > search flutter > point path to new downloaded sdk > invalidate cache and restart. you are done !

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that **ADB** was excluded from the **Antivirus**, so I've simply added an exception for the **ADB** and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you have cloned an app and the Flutter and Dart paths have not been set. Delete the ".idea" folder and set the paths and if there are any connected devices, they will load automatically.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I fixed the issue by putting the Android SDK in the PATH. I guess the Flutter plugin internally uses ADB to know the attached devices, so if you don't have it in your path, nothing can be done.

If that's your case, just type `adb` on a terminal. If it doesn't work, it means you have to put your Android SDK in the path, so you (and the Flutter plugin) can use it.

Just adding a screenshot just to clarify it a bit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue seems to be that my anti-virus program identified dart.exe as a threat and renamed it to dart.exe.000 - what worked for me was -

1. I downloaded the dart sdk and replaced the directory in my flutter directory 2)
   deleted flutter/bin/cache/flutter_tools.stamp 3) ran flutter doctor
   ...and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Solved For Me With:

1. Update flutter Plugin
2. File => Invalidate Caches / Restart => Invalidate and Restart
3. Update Android Studio
4. Update SDK
5. Install SDK in Only default Location android Studio
6. Tools => Troubleshoot Device Connection & read this and continue to Troubleshoot.
7. Use (RunAsAdmin(Windows) / root USER(Linux)) FOR RUN
8. **if you use physical Device**  , use code IN TERMINAL LINUX {

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adb
```

and Check if your Device Connected

```
adb devices
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was using another runtime, so I had to Ctrl+Shift+A -> Choose Runtime -> Default

Answer (score 0):

In your Terminal, run:

```
flutter upgrade
```

and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this**

Project Structure->Project settings-> project->Project SDK setting

*For me the project sdk was not set.*
After selecting the android sdk for the project, "loading devices" option is gone.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5031#issuecomment-838640744

Answer (score 0):

Kill the flutter processes from running first,
**taskkill /F /IM dart.exe** in your terminal in android studio
then type
**flutter run.** in the terminal again and press enter.

Afterwards your device you start showing.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers on this page works for Apple M1 cpus.
On Apple M1 chips the `adb` command does not work because it is not built for the Apple silicon. So that needs to be translated first to be runnable on the Apple chip. This is what [Rosetta 2](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861) does. To install it manually you can do this in the terminal (Thanks to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408379)):

`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

followed by

*invalidate cache and restart*

Answer (score 0):

**Just Restart your laptop/desktop.**

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu I used

```
adb kill-server
```

This fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I spent a full day trying to solve this issue. Finally, I located and deleted my SDK folder then downloaded new SDK platforms and tools via SDK TOOLS. Everything is working fine now.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/71110541/7905787

Answer (score -2):

Running Android Studio as Administrator (Windows) / Super User (Linux) fixed the issue for me.