# Android Studio device list is stuck on Loading... Mac

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I recently upgraded Flutter and today I noticed that when connecting my physical Android device the system does recognize but device list is stuck on `Loading...` and only options are to open iOS Simulator or the two emulators I installed, but even if I start the emulators then are no available to select to run the app..
I tried cleaning the cache a restarting Android Studio but didn't help..
What can be happened, or what can I check to find where the problem is?

Flutter doctor does see the phone dough.

```
[  +35 ms] [✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-4.0.pre.73, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale it-IT)
[   +1 ms]     • Flutter version 1.19.0-4.0.pre.73 at /Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter
[        ]     • Framework revision 94b7ff241e (6 days ago), 2020-06-04 18:53:00 -0700
[        ]     • Engine revision 859d892f1f
[        ]     • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-13.0.dev 54adfeb93f)
⣽[  +73 ms] executing: pod --version
[   +4 ms] List of devices attached
           3300f55e4cf61347       device usb:4250927104X product:a5xeltexx model:SM_A510F device:a5xelte transport_id:3
[  +25 ms] /Users/vinnytwice/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 3300f55e4cf61347 shell getprop                                                                                                        ⣻[  +52 ms] executing: /Users/vinnytwice/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses                                                                                                                  ⢿[ +123 ms] ro.hardware = samsungexynos7580                                                                                                                                                                   ⣟[ +990 ms] 1.8.1                                                                                                                                                                                             [ +521 ms] [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[        ]     • Android SDK at /Users/vinnytwice/Library/Android/sdk
[        ]     • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
[        ]     • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
[        ]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
[        ]     • All Android licenses accepted.
[   +2 ms] [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
[        ]     • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
[        ]     • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
[        ]     ✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 11.0.0.
[        ]       Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
[        ]     • CocoaPods version 1.8.1
[   +2 ms] [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[        ]     • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[   +1 ms] [✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[        ]     • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
[        ]     • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1
[        ]     • Dart plugin version 191.8593
[        ]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
[   +1 ms] [✓] Connected device (3 available)
[        ]     • SM A510F   • 3300f55e4cf61347 • android-arm    • Android 7.0 (API 24)
[        ]     • Web Server • web-server       • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
[        ]     • Chrome     • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.97
[        ] ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

## flutter run --verbose:

```
[ +246 ms] executing: [/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +69 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] daddc914c7629ee00117cdffb724c5bee8cbe97d
[   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/] git tag --contains HEAD
[ +300 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --contains HEAD
[   +5 ms] executing: [/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/] git describe --match *.*.*-*.*.pre --first-parent --long --tags
[  +32 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match *.*.*-*.*.pre --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] 1.19.0-5.0.pre-57-gdaddc914c
[  +17 ms] executing: [/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +15 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/master
[        ] executing: [/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +14 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +94 ms] executing: [/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +16 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] master
[   +9 ms] executing: sw_vers -productName
[  +19 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productName
[        ] Mac OS X
[        ] executing: sw_vers -productVersion
[  +18 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productVersion
[        ] 10.13.6
[        ] executing: sw_vers -buildVersion
[  +19 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -buildVersion
[   +1 ms] 17G65
[  +68 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +29 ms] executing: /Users/vinnytwice/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +16 ms] executing: /usr/bin/xcode-select --print-path
[  +14 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/xcode-select --print-path
[        ] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
[   +1 ms] executing: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
[ +160 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
[        ] Xcode 10.2.1
           Build version 10E1001
[   +4 ms] Xcode not found. Run 'flutter doctor' for more information.
[  +66 ms] List of devices attached
[  +10 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +115 ms] No supported devices connected.
[  +72 ms] The following devices were found, but are not supported by this project:
           Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
           Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.97
           If you would like your app to run on web, consider running `flutter create .` to generate projects for these platforms.
           
[  +25 ms] "flutter run" took 542ms.
[  +41 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:337:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:805:11)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:722:33)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart)
           #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:29)
           #6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #7      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #8      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
           #9      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1550:10)
           #10     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:18)
           #11     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:712:20)
           #12     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
           #13     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:332:21)
           #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #16     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #17     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #18     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #19     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #20     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #21     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #22     FlutterVersion.checkFlutterVersionFreshness (package:flutter_tools/src/version.dart)
           #23     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #24     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #25     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #26     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #27     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #28     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #29     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #30     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #31     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #32     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #33     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #34     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #35     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #36     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #37     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
           
           
[ +268 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 256ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your android device but you can't run your ios device because of this: `✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 11.0.0.`

Comment: @Uni yes, I know, I'm still on High Sierra, but I needed the latest flutter branch for web..On Catalina I'll be fine with iOS too..but I can't find what's missing here, I installed missing SDK 24, updated the tool.. cleaned cache..I might just reinstall fresh..

Comment: Sorry @Vincenzo but I don't see the log on your android device. I can't help you without the android logs.

Comment: How do I get the Android log?

Comment: try running flutter run -v or flutter run -verbose I'm not sure which command it is but its gonna spit a log.

Comment: Sure, it should be flutter run --verbose i guess.. let me try and I'll update the question with the log. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Uni I updated the question with the log, can you see anything wrong?

Comment: When running the app via run command the app starts fine on the phone..

Comment: not sure whats wrong with that but then there is an error log there.

Comment: @Uni I just reinstalled Android Studio fresh and it's now working again. It probably got some file corruption when upgrading flutter. Reinstalling it fresh took less than find the real cause..thanks for the help. I really appreciated it. Cheers.

Comment: Glad its now fixed. Good luck with your future projects :)

Comment: Delete .idea folder and set flutter and dart paths. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65368069/10123373).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue, after spending an hour, I realized that the new version doesn't support and has some bugs. The following worked for me,
I went to the terminal and ran this:
`$ flutter channel stable`, it switched to `branch stable` and then I ran `flutter --version` and it downloaded like before, ran flutter doctor, restarted android studio. Next thing to do , is to go to Tools>AVD Manager and open one of the AVDs. Once they're booted , it will automatically start showing up! Hope this helps! :) Keep coding ! :D

Comment: thanks for the help, I did restore the High-Sierra system disk and the problem went away. Now I upgraded to Catalina and I'm running the latest branch.  It's all good. Thanks again.