# Android Studio 4.1 adb got stuck

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-4.1

I upgraded my Android Studio to v4.1.

But adb commands are doesn't respond.
See:[image]

Therefore Android Studio Devices status stuck at "Loading Devices".
Like this:[image]

Does anyone know about this issue?

Comment: Do you use Flutter? Check these threads https://superuser.com/questions/1401980/android-studio-device-dropdown-stuck-on-loading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101178/android-studio-device-list-stuck-on-loading

Comment: no i am using kotlin

Comment: I'm having this issue on Android Studio Canary as well but I didn't experience this problem on Android Studio 4.1. The project that I'm working on uses Jetpack Compose and the only way to use its preview features are supported at the Canary version. So I checked ADB and it seems to work fine. Do you guys have any other solution ideas?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170650367

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It only works after restarting the computer, but the problem comes back again. I'm using MacOS

Answer (score 8):

On my situation, I had to delete the `platform-tools` folder found in SDK folder and replace it with the latest version.

Ex. **C:\Users\ (computer name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**, from this path you should find a folder named `platform-tools` then delete it.

Hence, I had to install the latest `platform-tools` from the official site of **android**. Here is the link, https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools. You only have to download the latest `platform-tools` specifically for your computer OS. After, unzip it to the path where you had deleted the old version of it.

By the way, `platform-tools` contains an executable file named `adb.exe`

Comment: this is only thing worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the latest Android Studio version. The only way to overcome it right now is to open the `Android Studio` terminal and run the `start-server` command manually:

```
/Users/[YOUR_USERNAME]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had been dealing with this bug as I stated in the comment section for a while in Android Studio Canary. But it seems like this is a general problem that newer Android Studio versions have. So, these steps would work for most people.

1. Uninstall Android Studio including the user settings. (Don't delete the folder. Uninstall properly.)
2. Download and install Android Studio 4.X or Canary as you prefer. And, do not accept old user settings if the Android Studio ask you to choose it. In my case, it did not ask but it worked like a charm.
3. Open the project

And voila.

Answer (score 0):

Same,
Took a while as there were a lot of processes running. Eventually my plugged in devices came up just as I was about to "File... Invalidate Caches and Restart"

Did it eventually come back up for you?

Comment: I tried "Invalidate cache and restart" before, but it didn't worked for me. When i restart my computer emulator works for one or two builds. It's a completely weird issue :)

Comment: I usally kill off adb process from task manager few times and it worked, but not always :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, having environment path of adb set caused stuck at "Loading Devices". I removed the environment path and restarted Android Studio, my device could connect again

It still not work with Memuplay emulator. I have to launch another emulator called LDPlayer and reboot Memuplay while LDPlayer still running, it will now connect to adb

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and i solved it by:

1. Try to reinstall Flutter
2. Reset Flutter SDK path in [Android Studio] under
   "Preference > Languages and Frameworks > Flutter".