# Android Studio 4.1 ADB Server Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-studio-4.1

I'm facing a problem with the ADB server. It's sometimes freezing on the "Loading Devices..." state. I'm always run this command and fix it.

```
adb kill-server & adb start-server
```

There is any solution or any people facing this problem.

[image: adb server]

Comment: got same issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385032/android-studio-4-1-adb-got-stuck
I rollback to Android Studio 4.0 for now.

Answer (score 0):

**Copy the android SDK path with platform-tool in CMD**
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvmgH.png)
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools >

after this connect USB cable and write some commands in terminal -

**adb tcpip 5555**

**adb kill-server**

**adb tcpip 5555**

**adb connect "Your IP Address"**

**adb connect "Your IP Address":5555**

then your device will be **connected to "Your IP Address"**

and you will get your device connected in android .