# Android device list showing in Android Studio got stuck

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Stuck in Loading Devices in Android Studio. Found below question in Stack Overflow but not helped,

[Android Studio device list stuck on loading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51101178/11630822)

I have tried invalidate cache and restart, but not solved.
Please any body help me to solve this issue.
My Android Studio version is 4.1.1
Thanks in Advance.

****Below Answer Solved my issue:****

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345049/11630822

Comment: remove any plugin that you recently installed..!

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli yes Tried that. but no change

Comment: how much do you wait?? keep waiting until it shows something else

Comment: @MRazaImtiaz I am waiting more than 2 hrs

Answer (score 7):

for mac users

1. Closing android studio.
2. Open **Activity Monitor**
3. Search **adb**
4. Force quit adb search results.

Comment: worked for me on MAC-OS

Answer (score 1):

i faced same problem and spend half day to fix this .finally done .
this problem is due to Adb not working well so you need to stop/disconnect adb
open  platform tools folder from C partition

C:\Users\addipc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

open command prompt from this folder via entering 'cmd' in path bar

press enter button and run command
`adb disconnect`

if not work with this then connect it again

run command this again

`adb tcpip 5555`

That's it

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is to reinstall Android Studio and ADB from scratch. Sounds like a bit an overhead but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me.

Simply disconnect your actual device and after loading finished, you can connect it again.

Answer (score 0):

While your android studio running open the task manager and go to details then end adb.exe task.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

1. Close Android Studio
2. open task manager
3. Kill adb process (on Task Manager on Windows)
4. Open Android Studio

**Solution 2:**

1. turned OFF your Wi-Fi
2. open

> C: \Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

3. open command prompt on given address
4. type

> adb disconnect

command in Command prompt

[image]

5. Restart Android studio

**Solution 3:**

Go to SDK folder delete platform-tools folder.. invalidate and restart the studio

**Solution 4:**
Some times you have Anti-Virus in your P.C (Personal Computer) that's why loading Device issue comes into play. In this case,Turn off Anti-Virus and restart your P.C (Personal Computer) and run Android Studio your issue will be solved.

Note: if these solution are not working then let me know i'll fix for you...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem too.Seems I had not installed

```
platform tools
```

Go to

```
setting->Android SDK->SDK Tools Then tick Android SDK tools
```

[image]