# Android Studio stuck on loading devices

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently running Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 in windows 10.
The problem I have is each time I start android studio the device list is stuck in loading devices.

[image: Stuck In Loading Device]

I tried these solutions

[android studio device list stuck on loading/51101178](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101178/android-studio-device-list-stuck-on-loading)

[android device list showing in android studio got stuck/65177069](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177069/android-device-list-showing-in-android-studio-got-stuck)

The soulutions provided in the threads sometimes work and sometimes don't but the real problem is even if I did fix it in the run time,  The next time I open android studio it's still there.

I already tried updating android studio to latest version, reinstalling android studio, deleting all the caches and plugins and resetting it to default. Completely Deleting Sdk folder and downloading again. But nothing helped I don't know where this problem could be originate from

Comment: The newer device manager isn't well, just wait for official updates or use a real device.
I miss the older device manager:(

Comment: Bumblebee Patch1 update is available , you can try in that if issue has been fixed.

Comment: @Nitish Already did. Results are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research and try and error I finally figured out what was going on.
Turns out my adb configuration was conflicting with genymotion's. Nothing could have done at the side of android studio. I went to the genymotion settings **ADB tab** and changed from **Use Genymotion Android Tools** to **Use custom Android SDK Tools** and it went away at last

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me, but I had to restart.

How did you figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score 17):

In my case deleting the "platform-tools" folder as Dyenal said didn't work because it said that the folder was open elsewhere (even when I had shut down android studio). If that's your case too, do this.

1. Close android studio
2. Go to your task manager
3. Go to the "Details" tab and look for "adb.exe" as seen in the image below.
4. Right-click on it and "End task".
5. Open android studio and pretend you weren't interrupted. Cheers :)

[image]

Comment: Killing adb did the trick for me.  On Mac, in Activity Monitor, quit the process.

Comment: I agree @Jamie, killing the .adb file from the Activity Monitor on mac is the certain solution for me.

Comment: I've just started running this command every time adb locks up

`pgrep adb | xargs kill -9 && adb start-server`

Answer (score 7):

Delete all adb tasks from activityMonitor (macOS) or taskmanager (windows). It will work then

Comment: activityMonitor (macOS) force quit adb worked.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go to SDK folder delete platform-tools folder.. invalidate and restart the studio..works for me!

Answer (score 1):

I only opened task manager and there were a bunch of adb.exe open so i ended all of them while android studio is running in the background so then adb.exe started again and then i go to android studio and find out that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary solution. Open terminal and type `adb devices`. Once your device starts showing up in terminal, it will start showing up in loading devices too.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs due to **Windows folder accessing** especially when you change the AVD folder.
Windows prevent access to Windows partition root. you have multi options for solving this problem.

1. Move `AVD` folder to another driver. Then define it on the Environment variable
2. Move the `AVD` to `C:\Users\<User>\.android\avd` folder. this folder is accessible for Android studio.
3. Run emulator from device manager, then type `adb devices` in cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

When using Android Studio, or any other IDE which use their own ADB, it is necessary to set Genymotion to use the correct ADB instead of its inbuilt one. It is documented here: https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/02_Application/#use-third-party-adbsdk